# Handling deserialization error

Tags: c#, json.net

I have class to deserialize from json

```
class SeeSharp
{
   public int Number;  
}
```

Good json is smth like

> {Number:1}

Wrong json which comes from PHP is

> {Number:false}

I use following way to handle deserialization error http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2012/03/debugging-deserialization-errors-in.html

When fails reading member of type string/int/double/bool/etc, I would like to set it's value to default of this type and mark that error as handled.

Currently, [JsonSerializationSettings.Error](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Error.htm) delegate doesn't allow to set value to failed member and doesn't show any information about type of member failed.

If there is an option to do that in another way, would be great to know it.

Comment: I actually have many classes to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this class?

```
public class SeeSharp
{
    public string Number
    {
        get
        {
            return _number.ToString();
        }

        set
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(value, out _number))
                _number = default(int);
        }
    }

    public int _Number { get; set; }
}
```

`JsonConvert` will use the string property `Number` to set data, which handles the parsing itself. And then use the property `_Number` in your code as `int`

Comment: Yes, I can, but I have a lot of such classes and fields. Decorating them in this manner takes time. Would be plan B :)